# Capitalization in tags: possible?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Can we please please have capitalization in tags? Is that possible? I would really like to see names capitalized in tags. I am guessing that it is default lowercase as that is what Stack Overflow does as well.

It is not critical but I would like to see God and Jesus capitalized in the tags out of reverence, and while we're at it allow capitalization for other names, too.

- Chris

Comment: Aw what's up with the down votes?

Comment: Down votes on meta.* mean "I disagree with this proposal."  One all meta sites besides MSO, downvotes (nor upvotes) have any effect on reputation.

Comment: FYI: I'm [not bothered](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6194/914) by treating Jesus and God as the same as any other proper name.  I [am bothered](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/152/73) by using lower case for proper names, however.  So -1 + 1 = 0.  I didn't vote either way.

Answer (score 4):

I honestly don't think having a tag system in all lower case is an issue of reverence, and the alternative of mixed case would make a legitimate mess.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the messy part. Just throwing it out there